# I need to get the primitive data type from json path using in-definite path

Tags: json, jsonpath, jpath

Given this document:

```
{
    "slide": [{
        "title": {
            "fontName": "Open Sans",
            "top": 188,
            "left": -22,
            "width": 597,
            "fontSize": 45,
            "valign": "bottom",
            "presetType": "Parallelogram",
            "fill": "#6bcad5",
            "halign": "left",
            "fontColor": "#f4dde6",
            "height": 192
        }
    }, {
        "picture": {
            "top": 25,
            "left": 54,
            "width": 1,
            "colorMode": "GRAYSCALE",
            "presetType": "Snip_Same_Side_Rect",
            "height": 1
        }
    }]
}
```

The following code returns `[54]`:

```
JSONArray obj = ctx.read("$.slide[?(@.picture)].picture.left");
```

But I need a primitive type, still maintaining the indefinite path.

Comment: Looking for naive way of doing this conversion JsonArray to primitive type

Comment: Could you provide the JSON against which you are executing this jsonpath?

Comment: `{
  "slide": [{
   "title": {
    "fontName": "Open Sans",
    "top": 188,
    "left": -22,
    "width": 597,
    "fontSize": 45,
    "valign": "bottom",
    "presetType": "Parallelogram",
    "fill": "#6bcad5",
    "halign": "left",
    "fontColor": "#f4dde6",
    "height": 192
   }
  }, {
   "picture": {
    "top": 25,
    "left": 54,
    "width": 1,
    "colorMode": "GRAYSCALE",
    "presetType": "Snip_Same_Side_Rect",
    "height": 1
   }
  }]
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

> Please note, that the return value of jsonPath is an array, which is also a valid JSON structure. So you might want to apply jsonPath to the resulting structure again or use one of your favorite array methods as sort with it.

Note: if you are using the Java implementation then an [issue](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/375) has already been raised for this and the response to that issue reiterated the above point.

So, as long as you use a filter you'll need two calls, for example:

```
String json = "...";

DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(json);

// capture the JSONArray
JSONArray obj = ctx.read("$.slide[?(@.picture)].picture.left");

// read the first value from the JSONArray
// prints "54"
System.out.println(obj.get(0)); 

// alternatively, push the JSON representation of the JSONArray back through JsonPath
Integer value = JsonPath.read(obj.toJSONString(), "$[0]");
// prints 54
System.out.println(value);
```